# Trying to grade quiz on javascript + local storage not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have been trying for many days to creating a scoring system on my quiz so that the user upon clicking submission and being redirected to the next page can see their score. Every time I try to add a scoring mechanism it doesn't work but it also messes up the local storage aspect of my website. The following below is my quiz.js file.

```js
function saveResult(studentID, score, givenname, familyname) {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem("studentID", studentID);
    localStorage.setItem("score", score);
    localStorage.setItem("givenname", givenname);
    localStorage.setItem("familyname", familyname);
  }
}

function getResult() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.getItem("studentID") !== null) {
      var studentID = document.getElementById("studentID");
      studentID.textContent = localStorage.getItem("studentID");

      var score = document.getElementById("score");
      score.value = localStorage.getItem("score");

      var givenname = document.getElementById("givenname");
      givenname.textContent = localStorage.getItem("givenname");

      var familyname = document.getElementById("familyname");
      familyname.textContent = localStorage.getItem("familyname");

    }
  }
}

function validate() {
  var errMsg = "";
  result = true;

  var google_e = document.getElementById("google_e").checked;
  var yahoo_e = document.getElementById("yahoo_e").checked;
  var javaScript = document.getElementById("javaScript").checked;
  var aliexpress = document.getElementById("aliexpress").checked;
  var duckDuckGo = document.getElementById("duckDuckGo").checked;

  var q1 = document.getElementById("google").checked;
  var q2 = document.getElementById("Archie").value;
  var q3_1 = document.getElementById("javascript").checked;
  var q3_2 = document.getElementById("aliexpress").checked;
  var q4 = document.getElementById("define_search_engine").value;
  var q5 = document.getElementById("percentage_of_usage_of_google").value;

  var score = 0;


  if (q1) {
    score += 1;
  }

  if (q2) {
    score += 1;
  }

  if (!(google_e || yahoo_e || javaScript || aliexpress || duckDuckGo)) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "Please select one option which is NOT a search engine.\n";
    result = false;
  } else if (q3_1 && q3_2) {
    score += 1;

  }

  if (q4 == "") {
    errMsg = errMsg + "Please write something for defining a search engine.\n";
    result = false;
  } else if (q4.match(/web search/i)) {
    score += 1;

  }

  if (!q5.match(/[0-9]/)) {
    errMsg = errMsg + "Please use numbers only.\n";
    result = false;
  } else if (q5.match(/92/)) {
    score += 1;

  }

  if (errMsg != "") {
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = errMsg;
  } else if (score == 0) {
    document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "Score is zero";
    result = false;
  } else {
    saveResult(studentID, score, givenname, familyname);
  }

  return result;
}

function init() {
  if (document.getElementById("quizpage")) {
    document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = validate;
  } else if (document.getElementById("resultpage")) {
    getResult();
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

My HTML is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" >
  <meta name="description" content="Homepage" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5, tags" />
  <meta name="author" content="Mihir"  />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/quiz.js"></script> 
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body id = "quizpage">
    <header> 
    <a href="index.html" >
        <img src="styles/images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="topic.html">Topic</a></li> 
                <li><a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a></li>
                <li><a href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    </header>

    <!--This page is pretty much built on lab 2 helpdesk we did in week 2-->
    
    <form id="myform" method="POST" action="result.html">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Student Details </legend>
            <p><label for="studentID">Student ID</label>    
                <input type="text" name= "StudentID" id="studentID" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{7}|\d{10}" title="Please ensure you are writting your Student ID correctly (numbers only)" size="10" required="required"/>
            </p>
    
            <p><label for="givenname">Given Name </label>
                <input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z-\s]+" name="Givenname" id="givenname" maxlength="25" size="10" required="required"/>
            </p>

            <p><label for="familyname">Family Name </label>
                <input type="text" pattern="[^0-9]+" name="Familyname" id="familyname" maxlength="25" size="10" required="required"/>
            </p>
        
            </fieldset>

        <fieldset>  
            <legend>Questions </legend> 
            <p> 1) What is the most famous search engine in the world</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="most_famous_search_engine" id="google" value="google" required="required" /> 
                <label for="Google">Google </label>
            
            <input type="radio" name="most_famous_search_engine" id="bing" value="bing" />
                <label for="Bing">Bing</label>
                
            <input type="radio" name="most_famous_search_engine" id="yahoo" value="yahoo" />
                <label for="Yahoo!">Yahoo!</label>
            </p>
    
            <p><label for="first_search_engine">2) What is the first search engine called?</label>
                <br>
                <select name="First_search_engine?" id="first_search_engine" required="required">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="Google">Google</option>
                    <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
                    <option value="Archie">Archie</option>
                </select>
            </p>


            <p> 3) Which one of these are <strong><u> NOT</u></strong> a search engine?</p>
            <p><label for="Google">Google </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Not_search_engine" id="google_e" />
    
            <label for="Yahoo">Yahoo!</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Not_search_engine" id="yahoo_e" />
    
            <label for="JavaScript">Javascript</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Not_search_engine" id="javaScript" />
    
            <label for="Aliexpress">Aliexpress</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Not_search_engine" id="aliexpress" />
    
            <label for="DuckDuckGo">DuckDuckGo</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Not_search_engine" id="duckDuckGo" />

            
            <p><label for="define_search_engine"> 4) Summarise/define what a web search engine is </label>
                <br>
                <textarea id="define_search_engine" name="define_search_engine" placeholder="Write your answer here..." rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
            </p>

            <p>5) What percentage of the internet uses Google (rounded to 2 figures) </p>
            <input type="text" name="percentage_of_usage_of_google" id="percentage_of_usage_of_google" pattern="\d*" />
           <br>
           <br>
         <input class="sending" type="submit" value="Book"/>   
         <input class="sending" type= "reset" value="Reset Form" /> 
        </fieldset>  
    </form>
    <h3><span id = "err"></span></h3>
<footer> 
     <p> Contact Information: <a  href="mailto:103075328@student.swin.edu.au">Mihir Bhadauria's Email</a></p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I am basically trying to program it so that when I click the submit button and it goes to result.html, the score value appears.

I am grateful for any criticisms or suggestions any of you may have.
P.S if you guys are not busy can you please also tell/guide me as to how I can check user ID attempts and then stop them from redoing more than 3 times.

Once again THANK YOU guys

Comment: This question would be a lot more answerable with the [matching HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't think anyone is interested in recreating it for you.

Comment: @JohnPavek I am sorry I didn't know that. I'll add the HTML